# How to query data from mongodb batch by batch using nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query data from mongo collection where collection has 1 million records and it might grow. So what I need here is I need to query from mongo collection batch by batch (like pagination). As of now only idea I have is to limit and skip the records while querying like below.

```
  Collection.find(query, fields, { skip: 100, limit: 100 }, function(err, results) { ... });
```

I heard using skip would again impact performance as it would go through each record of the collection from starting to skip. Is there any other optimized way here? Is there any concept of bookmarking in mongodb?

Comment: Why exactly you need to it batch by batch? `Collection.find()` returns a cursor which already retrieves data in batches internaly.

Comment: @AlexBlex I need to stream it to client batch by batch. How can I do that. Please suggest.

Comment: Iterate the cursor, accumulate records in the local buffer up to the size of the batch, send it to the client, discard the buffer, repeat untill the cursor is exhausted.